# Reference a different sheet in Excel based on the text in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to make a drop down list in a cell in Excel that a formula in VBA will reference.

For instance, this is my code:

```
    Worksheets("Input").Range("name").Select
    ActiveCell = Application.Xlookup(Worksheets("Input").Range("phone"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("T:T"))
End Sub

Sub bizlookup()
    Worksheets("Input").Range("company").Select
    ActiveCell = Application.Xlookup(Worksheets("Input").Range("phone"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("U:U"))
End Sub

Sub emaillookup()
    Worksheets("Input").Range("email").Select
    ActiveCell = Application.Xlookup(Worksheets("Input").Range("phone"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("V:V"))
End Sub

Sub addresslookup()
    Worksheets("Input").Range("address").Select
    ActiveCell = Application.Xlookup(Worksheets("Input").Range("phone"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("W:W"))
End Sub

Sub cszlookup()
    Worksheets("Input").Range("csz").Select
    ActiveCell = Application.Xlookup(Worksheets("Input").Range("phone"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("X:X"))
End Sub
```

Instead of "Worksheets("Master"), I want that to be a variable that changes the sheet depending on the text in a cell. Any ideas?

This is a quick mockup of my frontend form

[image: This is a quick mockup of my frontend form]

Comment: Worksheets(Range("A1").Value).....   where cell A1 can have any value. Better is to give a name at A1 (named range) e.g "THE_WS" and call:  Worksheets(Range("THE_WS").Value).....

Comment: Side note: it's a good idea to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code.